# Dynamically add hbox and elements inside hbox

Tags: extjs

I am using extjs 3.4

I would like to add dynamically hbox (because all labels must be horizontal) and items inside this hbox. Everything is dynamically added.

What I have already tried:

```
panel.items.add(Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
                            layout: {
                                type: 'hbox'
                            },
                            defaults: {
                                bodyPadding: 10,
                                margin: '10 0 10 10',
                                height: 100
                            }};
```

In this point I have error:

> types[(config.xtype || defaultType)] is not a constructor

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
panel.add({
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    defaults: {
        bodyPadding: 10,
        margin: '10 0 10 10',
        height: 100
    },
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: "First Field",
        name: 'firstField'
    }, {
        fieldLabel: "Second Field",
        name: 'secondField'
    }]
});
```